# Read the colour of multiple cells and depending on the colour, return a colour to another cell

Tags: excel, vba, colors

I want to read through multiple cells in a row and depending if they are all formatted green, turn a separate cell green.

If one cell in the row is either red or has no colour the cell will remain with red or no colour, then loop through my table to read each row and return a format in one column of cells.

And when I click my update button which brings new data into the table, the column of cells will reset to no colour then be formatted.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
Sub CS_Click()

Range("D6:D37").Interior.ColorIndex = 0

Dim Range1 As Range

Dim Range2 As Range

    For RR = 1 To 33
     For CC = 1 To 31

        Set Range1 = Cells(RR + 5, CC + 6)
        Set Range2 = Cells(RR + 5, CC + 3)

        If Range1.Interior.ColorIndex = 0 Then
            Range2.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        ElseIf Range1.Interior.ColorIndex = 38 Then
            Range2.Interior.ColorIndex = 38
        ElseIf Range1.Interior.ColorIndex = 50 Then
            Range2.Interior.ColorIndex = 50
        End If
    Next
 Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Where does `CC` come from?

Comment: Sorry I'm missing a line which is: For CC = 1 To 31

Comment: Which cell do you want formatted? The cell that is formatted in your code jumps position but in your question you say just one column?

Comment: This code appears to scan rows 6 thru 38, columns 6 thru 39 - so the range `F6:AM38` - and every time it finds a cell with colourindex of 0,38 or 50 - it copies the same colour to the cell 3 columns to the left. Is that what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use something like the following. This will loop through a range and test each row in the range for the `ColorIndex` of that row. It will then update a destination row with the `ColorIndex` of your choice

```
Sub CS_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, RowRng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim RowNo As Long
    Dim ClrIndex As Long
    Dim ChangeClr As Boolean

    ' The range of your source data
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("G6:AM37")

    For Each c In rng.Columns(1).Cells
        ClrIndex = -4142
        ChangeClr = False
        RowNo = c.Row - rng.Cells(1).Row + 1
        On Error Resume Next
        Set RowRng = Nothing
        Set RowRng = rng.Rows(RowNo).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not RowRng Is Nothing Then
            Select Case RowRng.Interior.ColorIndex
                ' Case 50
                Case 50
                    ClrIndex = 50
                    ChangeClr = True
                ' Blank rows
                Case -4142
                    ChangeClr = False
                ' Others not defined, Null (Mixed color rows) and color 38 rows
                Case Else:
                    ClrIndex = 38
                    ChangeClr = True
            End Select

            If ChangeClr = True Then
                ' Update the 'rng.Coloumns.Count + 1' with the offset of your destination cell
                c.Offset(0, -3).Interior.ColorIndex = ClrIndex
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tom thank you I will try that, and to your previous comment I'd like it to return a format to cells D6:D37, so depending on the colour of cells in G6:AM6 return a colour to D6, then loop through the rows until D37

Comment: @cistrat Ok my ranges are a little bit off. So the range you're testing against is `G6:AM37` and the destination cells are `D6:D37` ?

Comment: yes, so for each row G6:AM6 through to G37:AM37 and destination is D6:D37

Comment: Just realised its returning all the D cells the pink color, even if the cells G:AM are all green - is there a way to change this?

Comment: Is the colorindex of the cells definitely 50?

Comment: Are you sure all the rows in the range are the same colour? It will return `Null` if any of them are different

Comment: Ah sorry, ive just realised that your code is reading every cell in the row, my table has some cells with no data and therefore aren't formatted any colour. I tried to add a picture to explain better but it won't allow me! previously when i was formatting the range G6;AM37 i used a variant to search for numbers in the cells which then changed the colour depending on the number, would there be a way to incorporate that into this code? Sorry for all the questions!

Comment: You're right it is - you could modify it to skip out the cells that aren't to be tested. Which columns are omitted?

Comment: They are different in each case, and i have a button that brings in new data when a person is selected so will be different then too. so unfortunately wont work by skipping out data

Comment: do the cells that should be skipped have values in them or not?

Comment: Have updated my answer. It will ignore all cells without anything in them

Answer (score 0):

I think your code can be simplified to:

```
Sub CS_Click()

    Range("D6:D37").Interior.ColorIndex = 0

    For RR = 1 To 33
        Set Range2 = Cells(RR + 5, 4)
        For CC = 1 To 31
            Set Range1 = Cells(RR + 5, CC + 6)
            c = Range1.Interior.ColorIndex
            If c = 38 Or c = 50 Then
                Range2.Interior.ColorIndex = c
                Exit For ' remove this line as necessary
            End If
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

If you leave the `Exit For` line in, then the colour in column D will change based on the *first* pink or green cell it gets to. If you remove it, it will change the colour on *each* pink or green cell - resulting in column D representing the *last* green or pink colour it detected.